# Find the nearest nonzero element and corresponding index in a 2d NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2d array named `array` and a 2d index:`(x,y)` and I want to get the nearest nonzero element to `(x,y)`, and get the corresponding index of the element in `np.nonzero(array)`

Answer (score 8):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one approach -

```
def nearest_nonzero_idx(a,x,y):
    idx = np.argwhere(a)

    # If (x,y) itself is also non-zero, we want to avoid those, so delete that
    # But, if we are sure that (x,y) won't be non-zero, skip the next step
    idx = idx[~(idx == [x,y]).all(1)]

    return idx[((idx - [x,y])**2).sum(1).argmin()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: a
Out[64]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [65]: x,y =(3,5)

In [66]: nearest_nonzero(a,x,y)
Out[66]: array([5, 5])
```

**Approach #2 :** Here's another approach with focus on performance that avoids the second step from previous approach of skipping the `(x,y)` point from the array of non-zero indices by temporarily setting the point to `0`, getting those non-zero indices and then setting back the original value into it. Also, we could use `np.nonzero` to store the `row, col` indices and then perform the distance computing with those.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def nearest_nonzero_idx_v2(a,x,y):
    tmp = a[x,y]
    a[x,y] = 0
    r,c = np.nonzero(a)
    a[x,y] = tmp
    min_idx = ((r - x)**2 + (c - y)**2).argmin()
    return r[min_idx], c[min_idx]
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [110]: a
Out[110]: 
array([[3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2]])

In [111]: x,y =(3,5)

In [112]: nearest_nonzero_idx(a,x,y)
Out[112]: array([1, 5])

In [113]: nearest_nonzero_idx_v2(a,x,y)
Out[113]: (1, 5)

In [114]: %timeit nearest_nonzero_idx(a,x,y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.1 µs per loop

In [115]: %timeit nearest_nonzero_idx_v2(a,x,y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.85 µs per loop
```