# Distance to boundary represented by 2D/3D NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, geometry

I have large 2D/3D NumPy arrays of binary values. 1s represent boundaries and 0s represent regions. Accompanied by a step size array that indicates the size of step in each dimension.

I am looking for an efficient program that can find (one of) the nearest boundary element to a given element. Distance is euclidean distance.

A 2D example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

step_size = np.array([5,5])  # size of step in each dimension
arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
sns.heatmap(arr, annot=True, cbar=False, linewidths=.3)

a = (0,2)  # a given element index
b = (1,0)  # nearest boundary element index, which is to be found by the program

a_coor = np.multiply(np.array(a), step_size)  # array([0,10])
b_coor = np.multiply(np.array(b), step_size)  # array([5,0])

distance = np.linalg.norm(a_coor-b_coor)  # 11.18
```

[image]

Comment: For 2D arrays see also: [Find the nearest nonzero element and corresponding index in a 2d NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43306291/7851470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a job for a nearest neighbour search:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

step_size = np.array([5,5])  # size of step in each dimension
arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
sns.heatmap(arr, annot=True, cbar=False, linewidths=.3)

# get boundary pts (+0.5 to center for plot)
boundary = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(arr)) + 0.5

# create tree
tree = KDTree(boundary)

# get zero points to test for
zeros = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(~arr)) + 0.5

# get nearest neighbour boundary point for each zero
distance, index = tree.query(zeros)

# plot the results
for i, pt in enumerate(zeros):
    plt.gca().plot([pt[1], boundary[index[i,0]][1]], [pt[0], boundary[index[i,0]][0]], 'r')
```

The `KDTree` can calculate `k` neighbours easily and gives you back both the Euclidean `distance` and the `index` of the result in the original tree. A really useful tool. See the plot below:

[image: First nearest neighbour]

Also the result for second nearest neighbours, pass `k=2` to `query` and plot with:

```
# plot the results
colors = ['r', 'b']
for i, pt in enumerate(zeros):
    for k in range(index.shape[1]):
        plt.gca().plot([pt[1], boundary[index[i,k]][1]], [pt[0], boundary[index[i,k]][0]], colors[k])
```

[image: second nearest neighbour]

Comment: Thanks! Really impressive. How can the `step_size` also be included? Here for simplicity I set them all to 5, but they are not equal necessarily.

Comment: The `KDTree` just needs an array of points, they don't have to be integers so you could include that there. Alternatively, to fit with the question here, the Cartesian distance between neighbours is given by `delta = boundary[i] - boundary[index[i,0]]` so you could easily add any step size here, even uneven step sizes, eg. `d = delta * (6,4)` where `(6,4)` is your step size. I would then use `np.linalg.norm(d)` to get your Euclidean distance. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you. There is this other related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022427/find-nearest-transition-in-n-dimensional-array) of mine that now I think could be solved using a similar approach. At least for 2D/3D versions of it, which would be still fine.

Comment: @Reveille I just had a look at your linked question and I think a nearest neighbour search would work well in that case too.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the locations of all `1`s, obtain the euclidean distances to the given location, and return the smallest using [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) on the result:

```
def nearest_boundary(x, loc):
    ones = np.c_[np.where(arr == 1)]
    dist = ((ones - loc)**2).sum(1)
    return ones[dist.argpartition(0)[0]]
```

---

Some examples:

```
nearest_boundary(arr, (0,2))
# array([1, 0], dtype=int64)

nearest_boundary(arr, (2,4))
# array([3, 6], dtype=int64)
```

With a 3D array:

```
np.random.seed(2)
arr = np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.8,0.2], size=(3,5,4))

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1]]])

nearest_boundary(arr, (0,3,0))
# array([0, 4, 0], dtype=int64)
```